# Setting a custom 404 page for a specific URL in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Can I set a 404 event to go to a page thats not 404 if its from a specific URL?

eg say I have normal users going to /404/ with:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404/
```

in htaccess, and I have an admin section thats /admin/, if an admin user for whatever reason clicks a link that's invalid how-can I make them goto /admin/404/ (being a separate page from the normal 404 page) instead of /404/?

I'm guessing a rewriteCond of some kind?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, it should work with some minor changes

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errorpage.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/$ [NC]
RewriteRule errorpage.html /errorpage_admin.html [L]
```

Comment: How about you try this. Use two .htaccess files. Put one in your root directory, and specify ErrorDocument for entire site, and put one .htaccess file inside /admin/ directory, and only specify different 404 page, no other rules, just ErrorDocument. .htaccess file inside /admin/ directory takes precedence over .htaccess inside your root directory. Maybe that can work?

Comment: perhaps.. except the /admin/ folder does not exist.