# Custom 404 for selected URL without ErrorDocument

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I am trying to display custom 404 page for the documents or folder or file or link which may or may not exist but i still want to show a message of 404 to visitor for some purpose.

I have checked [Setting a custom 404 page for a specific URL in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487350/setting-a-custom-404-page-for-a-specific-url-in-htaccess) and [Setting a custom 404 page for a specific URL in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487350/setting-a-custom-404-page-for-a-specific-url-in-htaccess)

Code :

```
RewriteRule ^foo.html$ /spoof404.txt [L,R=404,NC]
RewriteRule ^hello$ /spoof404.txt [L,R=404,NC]
RewriteRule ^file/example.php$ /spoof404.txt [L,R=404,NC]
```

With these code, i am successfully getting `404 Status in header` but it not displaying the contents of `spoof404.txt`

Note:

1. I am not looking for Errordocument like 404 or 403
2. I am not looking for redirect
3. This is not a duplicate questions. i have already searched other part of stackoverflow before asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not looking for Errordocument like 404 or 403

Why not? That is exactly how you do this. There is no other way on Apache-only (without using another server-side script) to trigger a 404 HTTP status and serve a custom response.

For example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /spoof404.txt

RewriteRule ^foo\.html$ - [NC,R=404]
RewriteRule ^hello$ - [NC,R=404]
RewriteRule ^file/example\.php$ - [NC,R=404]
```

When you request `/foo.html` it will trigger a 404 and `/spoof404.txt` will be served.

When specifying a status ode outside of the 3xx range, the *substituion* string is ignored (hence the use of a single `-` - hyphen). In this case, the `L` flag is also superfluous, since it is implied when specifying a non-3xx `R` code.

---

**UPDATE:**

> how to block with parameters like `example.com/something.php?something=tokens&othertoken=token`

The `RewriteRule` directive matches against the URL-path only, to match the query string (everything after the first `?`) then you need an additional *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) and check against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

For example, to match that *exact* URL (although case-insensitively) and trigger a 404:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^something=tokens&othertoken=token$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^something\.php$ - [NC,R=404]
```

Comment: `Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.` i am getting this instead of contents of `spoof404.txt`

Comment: No, using `FallbackResource` and `ErrorDocument 404` together is perfectly OK and is what you should be doing. There is no conflict here. Setting `ErrorDocument 404` allows you to trigger a custom 404 response from Apache - which is what you are doing here.

Comment: Where is `/spoof404.txt` located? Presumably in the document root of the site? And the `.htaccess` file is also in the document root? What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: In same folder where `.htaccess` located. i mean domain root folder. check my updated question for my current .htaccess full code

Comment: when i try `ErrorDocument 404 /something.html` or `ErrorDocument 404 /something.php` it working fine but `ErrorDocument 404 /something.txt` is not working

Comment: I use hotlink protection for external site? maybe it happen due to that. i am using `<FilesMatch ".(txt|ini|psd|log|sh)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>`

Comment: Yes, that "hotlink protection" would block the _subrequest_ for `/something.txt`. (That's not "hotlink protection" btw, that's simply blocking any request for files with any of those extensions - including from your own site.) But where is that code? It's not in the `.htaccess` code you posted. (`Order` and `Deny` are Apache 2.2 directives and formerly deprecated on Apache 2.4. If you are on Apache 2.4 then you should be using `Require all denied` instead.)

Comment: and one last question. how to block with parameters like `example.com/something.php?something=tokens&othertoken=token` how can i do this? like `RewriteRule ^something\.php?something=tokens&othertoken=token$ - [NC,R=404]`

Comment: No, not like that. The `RewriteRule` directive matches against the URL-path only, you need to use a _condition_ (`RewriteCond` directive) as well. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I see. it working but not as i want. it shows 404 even for `example.com/something.php` but i want to show 404 only for `example.com/something.php?something=tokens&othertoken=token` not for `example.com/something.php`

Comment: Make sure you are not seeing a cached response. The directive in my answer would only block `example.com/something.php?something=tokens&othertoken=token`, it would not block `example.com/something.php` only. (Assuming `/something.php` does actually exist.)

Comment: Your right. I tried in private window and it working fine.

Comment: I use `apache 2.4.37` so i have to use `<FilesMatch ".(txt|ini|psd|log|sh)$"> Require all denied </FilesMatch>`

Comment: Yes, although you need to make sure you are using the Apache 2.4 mod_authz_core directives throughout since you can get unexpected results if the two are mixed.

Comment: Ok, i got it. Thanks for helping.